# PrintJS Styling of action buttons

Tags: styling, printjs

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to style the action (re' print & cancel buttons) from the PrintJS iFrame ?
Those 2 buttons  are both labelled  cr-button respectively with classes 'action-button' and 'cancel-button'...
Many thanks & BR,
JMB

Answer (score 1):

The library itself does not render a print or cancel button, these must be implemented in your code somewhere. The library iframe is used to prepare the print job, but it is hidden and even deleted once the job is complete.